# Different ANDROID_IDs for work and personal app

Tags: android-identifiers, android-for-work

I am using following code to get ANDROID_ID

String androidID = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                Secure.ANDROID_ID);

But for work profile I am getting a different ANDROID_ID for the same app than when deployed as a normal user app.

Are two different ANDROID_IDs generated for work and personal ?

Answer (score 0):

I definitely see that behavior on our devices.  You can test it in the command line using adb.  Here's a sample script: (the XXXXX returned is just me anonymizing the android_IDs from our system).

```
$ adb shell pm list users
Users:
    UserInfo{0:Owner:13} running
    UserInfo{10:Work profile:30} running

$ adb shell settings --user 0 get secure android_id
XXXXXX6d13c171c

$ adb shell settings --user 10 get secure android_id
XXXXXX6b3d28a2c9
```